# Trying to get property 'user' of non-object Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have an error that I do not understand why I get it.
I have search in a lot of threads about this error and I did not find the fix corresponding to me.

Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
Trying to get property 'user' of non-object

On the line `{{ $contact->messages->last()->user->name }}` in the template blade (see bellow).

```
class Contact extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'title', 'status',
    ];

    public function messages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ContactMessages', 'contact_id', 'id');
    }
}

class ContactMessages extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'contact_id', 'user_id', 'message', 'read',
    ];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\User', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
}

class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('contact.index')
            ->with('contact_list', Contact::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->latest()->paginate(10));
    }
}
```

```
// In my template view:
                @foreach($contact_list as $contact)
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{ $contact->id }}</td>
                    {{ dd($contact->messages->last()->user->name) }} // This display me the good result!
                    <td>{{ $contact->messages->last()->user->name }}</td> // This display me the Laravel error
                    <td>{{ $contact->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $contact->updated_at->diffForHumans() }}</td>
                  </tr>
                @endforeach
```

Thanks.

Comment: sounds like a contact doesn't have messages so `last` on the collection of messages would return `null`, which isn't an object ... putting a `dd` into your loop isn't going to help because that will only show you the first iteration than die, your loop is going to potentially run many iterations, not just one

Comment: @lagbox I have edited my template view, refresh your page. It's working using dd() but it's not working without this. Using dd it display me "SUNSHINE" that is the good username.

Comment: again, a loop can run many times, adding the `dd`, dump and die, is killing it after only 1 iteration. the error isn't coming from the first iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common reason is that something in this chain is empty. You can use `if` statements to prevent error. This is one way to do that:

```
@if($contact->messages->last())
    @if($contact->messages->last()->user)
        {{ $contact->messages->last()->user->name }}
    @endif
@endif
```

Comment: but you are forgetting here everytime you use `last()` you are querying database. So, I would suggest to eager load your relationship and do a check without the parenthesis